# Compiling for Java X vs running on Java X

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, compilation, application-server

We've got an application that since it's beginning was compiled with Java 6, because it was required to run on IBM WAS 8.0, but we are starting to migrate to Wilfly, which will be running on a JDK 8.

So the question is, if there's there any advantage/difference/problem/... on starting compiling the new application with Java 8, or should we leave it in Java 6 since all it's code is already in Java 6 and it won't take any advantage of the "new functionalities" of Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only going to run your code using a Java 8 JVM, there's no advantage to targeting Java 6 at compile time.

This sounds like a perfect opportunity to upgrade to a less-ancient version of Java.

Comment: I know that, the "problem" is that we will still have to generate one package compiled with java6 because not all clients will migrate to wildfly overnight. And by leaving it in java6 we wouldn't have to generate 2 different packages, and make sure that each client receives the correct package. That's why I'm asking if there's any advantage on doing that, besides finally migrating to less-ancient version of Java :)

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I didn't understand at first. In that case, no, there's no benefit to targeting Java 8. The "Does this answer your question?" comment links to a discussion of this issue.